# Java 13 and JavaFX 13 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to get some old code running again.

I originally wrote this project in java SE 10.0.2 but want to update everything so that it works with Java SE 13.0.2 and JavaFX 13. It works fine when I use Java 10 (I'm assuming because JavaFX was still included) but with Java 13 everything compiles and runs but nothing ends up showing up (it should pop up a window).

I'm new to StackOverflow so I can't embed images which is wonderful, but below is my module-info.java code and my build path includes a SQL jar and the necessary JavaFX jar files (also, yes, I named my package "Package").

```
module javafx13 {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires java.sql;
exports Package; }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction